# Como apago essa borda no Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Eu quero apagar essa borda que fica ao redor do Canvas, mas não estou conseguindo achar qual atributo que determina a existência dela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

O código:

```
class Tela():
    def __init__(self, resolucao:str):
        self.inst = Tk()
        self.inst['bg'] = 'black' 
        self.inst['relief'] = 'flat'
        
        resolucao = resolucao.split('x')
        print(resolucao)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.inst, background='black', bd=0
        , width=int(resolucao[0]), height=int(resolucao[1])-100)
        
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.inst.mainloop()

Tela('640x480')
```

Comment: experimenta: `self.canvas = Canvas(self.inst, background='black', bd=0, width=int(resolucao[0]), height=int(resolucao[1])-100,highlightthickness=0)`

Comment: Funcionou, valeu